# Loop is not completing , for datarow

Tags: c#-4.0, for-loop

I have this code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataTable.Rows.Count; i++)
{
     tempdatatable.Clear();
     var tempRow = dataTable.Rows[i];
     temp = dataTable.Rows[i][0].ToString();
     for (int j = 0; j < dataTable.Rows.Count; j++)
     {
          DataRow rows = dataTable.Rows[j];
          if (temp == rows[0].ToString())
          {
               tempdatatable.Rows.Add(tempRow[0], tempRow[1]);
               dataTable.Rows.Remove(rows);      //Update happen here
          }
          tempdatatable.DefaultView.Sort = "gscitations DESC";

          dataGridView1.DataSource = tempdatatable;
      }
 }
```

My question is,isn't rows missing in it? I mean when loop starts at `i=0`, then i remove rows in the inner loop, so `i` is also incremental and rows are also being removed,if i am right , loop will traverse half the iteration , because loop limit is handled by count method, am i right?
if yes? how can i fix it?

Comment: Why don't you just remove duplicate values from `dataTable` by applying `Distinct` method?

Comment: i also want to save the duplicate values then remove them, can i do it ?

Comment: Sure! You can find duplicates first by applying `.GroupBy(x => x)
                             .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
                             .Select(g => g.Key)`